# Uploading to a Specific Folder in Google Drive with Google REST API

Tags: rest, powershell, google-drive-api

I have successfully uploaded a local file off my computer to my Google Drive as a PDF. However, when the file was uploaded, it is labeled as Untitled and  not placed in any specific folder.

```
$GUploadBody= @"
--BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/pdf; charset=UTF-8

{
  "title": "$title",
  "parents": [{
    "id":"$parentfolder" 
    }],
  "mimeType": "$inputmime",
  "description": "$description"


}
--BOUNDARY
Content-Type: text/plain

$togoogle
--BOUNDARY--

"@
```

How do I make it so that the file uploaded is labeled with the file name, and how can I specify a folder in my Google Drive for that file to go to?

Here is the Invoke-WebRequest cmdlet I used:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -uri $GUploadURI -Method Post -body $GUploadBody -Headers $Guploadheaders -ContentType "application/pdf; charset=UTF-8" -UseBasicParsing
```

I have found the syntax for other languages like Java, but Powershell must be used for automation purposes.

Comment: Try checking this [github code](http://www.connorcg.com/powershell/2018/03/20/uploading-and-downloading-from-google-drive-via-api-with-powershell-and-oauth2.html), they have sample code for uploading to a specific folder for PowerShell and Drive API.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used powershell but in Google Drive v3 'title' field has changed to 'name' and 'parents' is just an array of folderIds (["folderId1", "folderId2"]).

In that case, I believe it should return an error but you could try it.

Comment: I tried that, but the content in the PDF file just reads exactly what I type in there. I think it might be a problem with the POST parameter.